# Как освободить порт из MySQL?

Tags: mysql, порт

вчера установил MySQL версии 5.5, потом узнал что есть последняя версия (8.0), удалил версию 5.5 сначала, скачал MySQL последнюю версию, теперь ошибку пишет что такой порт существует, удалил 8.0, установил обратно 5.5, та же ошибка пишет, вопрос как освободить порт? погулил, нужного решения не нашел. Заранее спасибо

Comment: вы как-то неправильно удаляли. При установке запускается служба, которая слушает порт. При удалении служба должна останавливаться и удаляться. У вас этого не произошло